# Can't remove component (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use this starter pack https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter

There Inserted component UserList to Home container

when I try just comment this field with import. `import UserList from '../../components/UserList'`;  I have error,I need remove this component

```
[webpack-isomorphic-tools] [error] asset not found: ./src/components/UserList/styles.scss
==>   Rendering routes error: TypeError: Cannot read property '_style' of undefined
```

I just remove import, why it's happens?

UserList component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import styles from './styles.scss';

type Props = { list: Array<Object> };

const UserList = ({ list }: Props) => (
  <div className={styles.UserList}>
    <h4>User List</h4>
    <ul>
      {list.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>
          <Link to={`/UserInfo/${user.id}`}>{user.name}1111</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

UserList.defaultProps = {
  list: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
  },
};

export default UserList;
```

SCSS USERLIST

@import '../../theme/variables';

```
.UserList {
  color: $color-white;

  ul {
    padding-left: 17px;

    li {
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
  }

  a {
    color: $color-white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see `src/components/UserList/styles.scs` and your UserList component, please?

Comment: updated, please check

Comment: But you already found a solution, correct?

Comment: yes I found....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Utils/html.js

there was requere `require('../components/UserList/styles.scss')._style +`